# how to use outclass instance in innerclass in java?

Tags: java

I want this to be an instance of an outer class of an inner class. 
I was originally going to use 'this' in innerclass.
I realized I should not be trying to use 'this'.
'this' is mean innerclass-instance, not outclass-instance...
What should I do?

Comment: `OuterClassName.this`

Comment: add some code, otherwise it's hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You use something like

```
Outerclass.this
```

for example. That allows you to denote elements of the enclosing outer class (assuming that the inner class is not static).

Comment: oh thank you very much!